# Why is my button not displaying in the iphone simulator but showing in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to display a button in a collection view, but it's not showing when I run it on the iphone simulator; however it clearly shows in the storyboard (refer to image). 
Also - I notice that when I add horizontal and vertical constraints it shows. When i delete the constraints however, the button completely disappears. Shouldn't some of the button display in the collection view since my coordinates don't seem to be off enough for the entire button to not display? Sorry if this is a lousy question - I just picked up ios development.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMOe4.png)

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT1HE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your `UIButton` seems to be getting smaller due to the auto-resizing of `UICollectionViewCell`. To fix the issue you can either set the `itemSize` property of the `collectionViewLayout` or by returning the `sizeForItem` if you're giving different size for each cell. Here's the code:

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 300)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```

Here's how you add it via `Size Inspector`:

1. Select the `Collection View Flow Layout` on the left
2. Then in the `size inspector` tab on the right you can give `Cell Size`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to do this through one of the inspector tabs?

Comment: I've added a screenshot for modifying in the size inspector.

Comment: hmm the button still seems to not display even after those changes

Comment: Add the constraints to the button to all 4 sides.

Comment: Thank you v much

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped then mark this as right and upvote it when you'll be able to.